# Ruby through RVM fails

Tags: ruby, bash, rvm

In constant battle to install Ruby 1.9.2 on an RPM system (OS is based off of CentOS), I'm trying again with RVM.

So once I install it, I then try to use it:

```
[root@quackwall ~]# rvm use 1.9.2
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136
[root@quackwall ~]# ruby
bash: ruby: command not found
[root@quackwall ~]# which ruby
/usr/bin/which: no ruby in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)
```

Now that's interesting; `rvm info` says something completely different:

```
[root@quackwall bin]# rvm info

ruby-1.9.2-p136:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux quackwall.highwow.lan 2.6.18-194.8.1.v5 #1 SMP Thu Jul 15 01:14:04 EDT 2010 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (i686-redhat-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.2.2 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.2p136"
    date:         "2010-12-25"
    platform:     "i686-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2010-12-25 revision 30365"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25 revision 30365) [i686-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136"
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin:bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136"
    GEM_PATH:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136"
    IRBRC:        "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

So I have RVM that says one thing and bash which says another. Any suggestions on how to get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using your root account?

```
[root@quackwall ~]
```

RVM is designed to work as a user's sandbox, unless you are doing a system wide install. For normal use installing using root permissions and paths will get it all screwed up.

[Installing system wide](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/deployment/system-wide/) is a lot more complicated so if it's just for you, use the standard install.

Also, notice that `rvm use 1.9.2` points to:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136
```

but:

```
which ruby
```

has no `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136` in the search path:

```
/usr/bin/which: no ruby in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)
```

If you intend to use system-wide installs, you either need to modify all `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` files for all users, or adjust `/etc/bashrc` or `/etc/profile`.

Comment: I run as root sometimes and I thought that this time it wouldn't affect anything. I'll try again today with a standard account.

Comment: This and moving the sourcing line for `rvm` to `.bashrc` since I use byobu/screen fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you didn't update your `.bashrc` as the directions noted.

Note, after updating `.bashrc` you will need to open a new bash terminal so it reloads the environment.

Comment: I did actually do that, but when I looked the directory it was pointing to ( $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ) doesn't exist...

Answer (score 0):

## Note

I've completely revised/clarified my answer in light of guidance/insight from [TheLQ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/342518/thelq).

### Answer

I got Ruby through RVM on after fresh install of OSX 10.7. For me, rvm failed no matter what with single user rvm. Sudo combined with some permission and environment $PATH changes to my user made it happen. Here's what I did:

```
sudo bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )</pre>
sudo rvm pkg install readline
sudo rvm install 1.9.3
```

Installing rvm from root user makes a shell script at /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
Pulled code from this executable and placed it in my .bash_profile so that .bash_profile was saved as:

```
[[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] ;
    true ${rvm_path:="/usr/local/rvm"}
    source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

The user group *RVM* was created during root user rvm install. Last thing I did was go to my preferences pane in OSX 10.7 and added my user to the new rvm group. Finally I reloaded my terminal and was able to install 1.9.3 through rvm single user.

Comment: I'm confused, what does your post add that others haven't already said? Also, just FYI, its kinda frowned upon to start posting links to your site as a new user. I personally don't care, but others will.

Comment: rvm had a substantial impact on ruby programming, brought lasting benefits, but honestly it's not the best anymore. I'm over it, and would rather stay agile. There's better stuff out there. Consider alternatives like [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [ry](https://github.com/jayferd/ry).